# HTML Email - Spec Char for Dagger not rendering in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

For some reason the special character for dagger is rendering fine internally and in outlook but not in gmail. Anybody have any clue why it may be being stripped out? We are using putsmail (litmus) to deploy the test but it shouldn't make a difference. We've tried with and without .

Again, it's rendering fine internally and in outlook but not displaying in gmail.

Comment: If I send an email to my own gmail address, it works fine. So can you provide some more details about what you did exactly? How was it encoded etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There seems to be an issue. I tried the following characters in an HTML email in Litmus:

```
html-&#134; - character-†
```

I found that the HTML character did not render in Gmail Desktop for Firefox, Gmail Desktop for IE, but rendered fine in Chrome.

AOL for Firefox and IE did not render either. Both characters showed up in every other major email browser.

So then I re-read [Mr Lister's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister) answer. Why would it work for him?

So I tried the same email in Putsmail and sent it to my Outlook and my Gmail accounts and found both versions showed up just fine. Except that in Gmail, it seems to be a double-dagger for HTML in every email client, but a single dagger from the keyboard.

My email is configured for UTF-8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`and the font I was testing with was Arial.

I don't have a great solution to offer.

It could be issues with various Gmail servers. It worked fine with Inbox by Gmail.

Consistently across all tests, the HTML version is the only one with any issues. The keyboard `†` renders fine in every client.

Good luck.

Comment: Ah, is that what the OP's doing wrong. I never thought of trying &#134;. because &#134; is not the right codepoint for a dagger. Character references are supposed to be Unicode values, not Windows-1252. So the correct one would be &#8224;. Or, just type the character; if you use UTF-8 you can just type anything!

Comment: If `&#134` is not the right code for dagger, then how come it works? - https://everythingfonts.com/ascii/codes/134 - You are correct, you can use `&#8224` as well. I would have tested with that instead, but `&#134;` came up first in my search for the right code. I generally do not recommend using extended characters above 127 without using the ASCII code in html, even with declaring UTF-8 because they don't always work correctly and show up as a glitch. Except in this case when inexplicably it seems to work just fine.

Comment: But the OP is complaining that it does NOT work just fine, not in all circumstances. What you see here is the browsers' error correction at work: character references between &#128; and &#159; that are not Unicode characters are translated to their Windows-1252 equivalents. But sometimes it goes wrong, so it's best to not count on that behaviour and use the _real_ Unicode value instead.